# Problem using Mongo Find with dynamic fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

If the community could assist with this, that would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to have dynamic search options for the mongo database. I assumed just making an element would work but I have not been able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I tried with manually having the values present such as {JobDepartment: "Accounting"}, and it works however would like it to be dynamic.

Console Outputs with searching for `/getJobs?jobDepartment=Accounting` vs `/getJobs?jobDepartment=Finance`

```
{ Active: true, JobDepartment: 'Finance' }
{ Active: true, JobDepartment: 'Accounting' }
```

Both send out the full document as below: (Please note there is a filter function but I am not including it in this snippet)

Res.send output is below:

```
[{"JobId":"61a7d727fd77be5a0a93d5bb","CompanyLogo":"/example.png","CompanyName":"Example LLC","JobTitle":"CFO","JobDepartment":"Accounting","JobType":"Full-Time","Salary":"$90,000","SalarySubType":"$90,000","Benefits":["Generous PTO","401K"],"JobTags":["React"],"AvailableTo":"US Only","JobLink":"Accounting-1d2a17797962"}]
```

The problem with the above output is that when I search for "Finance" it returns a document that has "Accounting". There is only one document however I am under the assumption that it is sending all documents rather than only for the ones that is within the element of "params".

```
// get job lists with filter options for candidates
const JobPost = require("../../models/jobPost");

module.exports = async (req, res) => {

  let JobTags = req.query.jobTags;
  let JobDepartment = req.query.jobDepartment;
  let JobType = req.query.JobType;
  
  let params = {};
  params['Active'] = true;
  
  if (JobTags !== undefined) { 
    params['JobTags'] = JobTags;
  } 
  
  if (JobDepartment !== undefined) { 
    params['JobDepartment'] = JobDepartment;
  }
  
  if (JobType !== undefined) { 
    params['JobType'] = JobType;
  }
  
  console.log(params);
  
  let ActiveJobs = await JobPost.find({params})
      .sort({CreatedAt: -1})
      .limit(1000);
  
  if (ActiveJobs == undefined) {
    res.send({"Invalid": 404})
  } else { 
    res.send(ActiveJobs);
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: why is your first snippet saying `Accounting: 'Accounting'` instead of `JobDepartment: 'Accounting'`??

Comment: And why is your params in the find() inside of `{}`, it is not supposed to be
Also an issue could be that Active is a string in your database and in params log it is a boolean, but idk how your database looks like.

Comment: if I look at your Res.send output I realize 2 things: First of all there is no field called Active to be matched, and there is no field called Accounting as mentioned in my first comment,

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum, I will edit the posting to have { Active: true, JobDepartment: 'Finance' } format for the console logs. If you look at the first version of the posting it was originally params[JobDepartment] = JobDepartment; which made that error, but I fixed that and was still having the same issue. When I edited to include  params['JobDepartment'] = JobDepartment; I did not add the new console logs. My apologies.

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum, Also Active is a boolean in the model. I will test the params not being inside a { } and report back.

Edit: That was it! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are very welcome ;)